# Ask for clues for the “It's All About the Miles”

Tags: python

I recently encounter a problem and I really cannot figure out how to solve it. It's a problem in Open Kattis.

Please visit https://uchicago.kattis.com/problems/uchicago.miles

By now, I know it's a recursion problem.

But how to define this recursive procedure? I don't know where should I start.

So please give me a clue or maybe some pseudocode.

Here I pasted my code for reading the input, and I convert the input data into dictionary.

```
AFItt = input().split()
A, F, I = map(int, AFItt[0:3])
tmin, tmax = map(float, AFItt[3:])
airport = []
ada ={}
ai= []

for _ in range(A):
    airport.append(input())

for _ in range(F):
    ffda = input().split()
    if ffda[0] + " " + ffda[1] not in ada.keys():
        ada[ffda[0] + " " + ffda[1]] = (float(ffda[2]), float(ffda[3]))
    else:
        ada[ffda[0] + " " + ffda[1]] += ((float(ffda[2]), float(ffda[3])))

for _ in range(I):
    ai.append(input())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give you a clue, but not sure whether it is efficient enough. I wrote a javascript version and it can produce the sample outputs correctly.

The idea of my solution is very simple: from the starting of the itinerary, find all possible next flights and keep appending to previous flight runs.

For example,

`for first 2 itinerary airports`, I will find all the possible flights and save it in an array list `[[fligh1], [flight2], [flight3]]`

after that, I will loop all the current possible runs, and continue to check if there existed an flight for the possible run to continue. If not, it is excluded, if yes, we append the flight to the list.

If flight1 and flight2 cannot continue, but flight3 has two possible flights to continue, my flight list will be changed to `[[flight3, flight4], [flight3, flight5]]`

A bit hard to me to explain well. Following is some code skeleton:

```
function findAllFlights(flightMap, 
                        currentFlights, 
                        currentItineraryIndex, 
                        itineraryList, minTime, maxTime){
    //flightMap is a map of all the flights. sample data:
    /*{'a->b':[{from: 'a', to:'b', depTime:'1', arrTime:'2'}, {another flight}, ... ],
       'b->c': [{from: 'b', to:'c', depTime:'1', arrTime:'2'}, {another flight}, ... ]}
    */ 

    //currentFlights is the result of current possible runs, it is a list of list of flights. each sub list means a possible run.
    //[[flight1, flight2], [flight1, flight3], ...]

    //currentItineraryIndex: this is the next airport index in the itineraryList
    //itineraryList: this is the list of airports we should travel.
    //minTime, maxTime: it is the min time and max time.

    if(currentItineraryIndex == 0){
        var from = itineraryList[0];
        var to = itineraryList[1];
        var flightMapKey = from+'->'+to;
        var possibleFlights = flightMap[flightMapKey];
        if(possibleFlights.length == 0){
            return [];
        }
        for(var i=0; i<possibleFlights.length; i++){
            //current flights should be a list of list of flights.
            //each of the sub list denotes the journey currently.
            currentFlights.push([possibleFlights[i]]);
        }
        return findAllFlights(flightMap, currentFlights, 1, itineraryList, minTime, maxTime);
    }else if(currentItineraryIndex == itineraryList.length - 1){
        //we have searched all the required airports
        return currentFlights;
    }else{
        //this is where you need to recursively call findAllFlights method.
        var continableFlights = [];
        //TODO: try to produce the continuable list of flights here based on above explanation.
        //once we have the continuable flights for current itinerary airport, we can find flights for next airport similarly.
        return findAllFlights(flightMap, continableFlights, currentItineraryIndex + 1, itineraryList, minTime, maxTime);
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still cannot figure out how solve it entirely. There are mainly two problems I don't know how to solve. The first one is how to calculate the time between two adjacent flights in a recursive way ?The second is  how to append flights in a recursive way?